# Ruby Web Server Get Useragent

Tags: ruby, http, user-agent

i build a own ruby web server and now i want to parse the user agent with a gem called userAgent.

My Problem is i don't know how to get the useragent from the request.

```
string = request.user_agent
user_agent = UserAgent.parse(string)
puts user_agent.browser
# => 'Chrome'
puts user_agent.version
# => '19.0.1084.56'
puts user_agent.platform
# => 'Macintosh'
```

i got this error:

```
server.rb:21:in `<main>': undefined method `user_agent' for "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n":String (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "request" object is not a request at all, just a first line of the http request. Here's what an http request with headers looks like:

```
GET /posts/32627211/ivc/ee27?_=1442483419256 HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627211/ruby-web-server-get-useragent
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,pt-BR;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2
Cookie: cookie here
```

Read farther into the request headers and you'll find your user-agent.

Building web servers is difficult. If the problem above is giving you troubles, wait until you have to implement request body (handling multipart attachments, especially) :)